# Inline ckeditor in IE9 browser works only once(within the popup panel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, inline, modalpopup

I have a main page and popuppanel(popuppanel content page have a div that goes as inline ckeditor) is used within this main page to show some details. If the same code is executed multiple times (i.e., ckeditor works many times), it is working in all other browsers other than IE9 (working even in IE8). However, first time execution is successful. The code that is being used is provided below.

**following error throw from 2nd time execution:**

```
CKEDITOR.inline is undefined
CKEDITOR.document is undefined
```

[OS-Windows7, browser-IE9, ckeditor-v4.0].

**Mainpage**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>main Page</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calljs(){
        ifrm1 = document.getElementById("if1");
        ifrm1.setAttribute('src', 'panelPage.aspx');
         $find('pup').show();
        }

    function closebtn(){
        $find('pup').hide();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
   </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
   <input type="button" onclick="javascript:calljs();return false;" value="Show"/>
       <div>
      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="pup" PopupControlID="popupPanel" PopupDragHandleControlID="popupPanel"
            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnOk" CancelControlID="BtnCancel"
            BackgroundCssClass="PopupBackground" Drag="True">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Button Style="display: none" ID="BtnOk" runat="server"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button Style="display: none" ID="BtnCancel" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="popupPanel" runat="server">
                 <iframe id="if1" src="" class="" style=""></iframe>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

**popuppage**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            CKEDITOR.inline(document.getElementById("ed"),{
                    toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic']]
             });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="ed" contenteditable="true">
    <p>dummy Text here</p>
    </div>
     <input type="button" onclick="javascript:parent.closebtn();return false;" value="hide" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a alternate solution for this issue

just i created **iframe** inside a **DIV** and i **removed the iframe and recreate** while closing the popup. its working fine and also it solves many other issues like **jquery $ undifend error** , **pagemethods not working on second time popup execution in ie9** and etc.

changes below:

**MainPage:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>main Page</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calljs(){
        ifrm1 = document.getElementById("if1");
        ifrm1.setAttribute('src', 'panelPage.aspx');
         $find('pup').show();
        }

    function closebtn(){
        $("#if1").remove();
        $("#iFrameDiv").html("<iframe src=''></iframe>");
        $find('pup').hide();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
   </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
   <input type="button" onclick="javascript:calljs();return false;" value="Show"/>
       <div>
      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="pup" PopupControlID="popupPanel" PopupDragHandleControlID="popupPanel"
            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnOk" CancelControlID="BtnCancel"
            BackgroundCssClass="PopupBackground" Drag="True">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Button Style="display: none" ID="BtnOk" runat="server"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button Style="display: none" ID="BtnCancel" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="popupPanel" runat="server">
<div id="iFrameDiv">
                 <iframe id="if1" src="" class="" style=""></iframe>
</div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```